# unable to load the request file

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, apache2

Hi I’m just new in codeigniter. My website works, this error after I'm migrate windows to ubuntu. in ubuntu I use vhost.

> An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file:
>   admin/layout.php

Here is my controller:

```
<?php 
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class C_login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_login');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('v_login');
    }

    function aksi_login(){
        $id_user = $this->input->post('id_user');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $where = array(
            'id_user' => $id_user,
            'password' => $password//md5($password)
        );
        $cek = $this->m_login->cek_login("tb_user",$where)->num_rows();
        if ($cek > 0) {
            $data_session = array(
                'nama'=>$id_user,
                'status'=>"login"
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
            $data['title']="Home";
            $data['model']=$this->M_data;
            $data['user']=$this->M_data->Get_data('tb_user');
            $data['Diag']=$this->M_data->Get_data('tb_diagnosa');
            $this->db->where('status !=',0);
            $data['all_rekam'] =$this->db->get('tb_diagnosa')->num_rows();
            $this->db->where('status',1);
            $data['ok_rekam'] =$this->db->get('tb_diagnosa')->num_rows();
            $this->db->where('status',2);
            $data['not_rekam'] =$this->db->get('tb_diagnosa')->num_rows();
            $tpl['content'] = $this->load->view('Admin/home',$data,TRUE);
            $this->load->view('admin/layout',$tpl);
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','id_user atau password anda salah silahkan diulangi lagi!!!!');
                redirect('C_login','refresh');
        }
    }
    function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url('C_login'));
    }

 }


 /* End of file C_login.php */
 /* Location: ./application/controllers/C_login.php */ ?>
```

Comment: File names in Windows File systems (ntfs/fat) are case insensitive but in linux file systems they are case sensitive. most likely your file name is "Layout.php". Windows is able to open such file when you refer to it as "layout.php" but linux can't.

Comment: check if you have a file  *admin/layout.php*

Answer (score 0):

For load view file in Codeigniter... you need to have the following view file in your view directory.

"Application/View/admin/layout.php" you don't have this file that is why you are getting this error.